# Use quiver to plot a 2D vector map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of coordinate pairs (x, y) and I want to plot this set using `quiver`. I tried to check other relevant questions but I'm still struggling with this.

Imagine I want to plot 4 vectors with two arrays with x and y coordinates:

```
x = arange(0, 3)
y = arange(0, 3)

# vectors x coordinate values
fx = (0, 1, 1, 2)    
# vectors y coordinate values
fy = (1, 0, 1, 2)

X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Q = quiver(X, Y, fx, fy)
```

The result is not 4 but 9 vectors, why?

Comment: Why you tagged with signal-processing? Is the question actually apply in this area? Just ask for curioustiy

Comment: You need to fill out you fx and fy as well.  There shape needs to match the shape of X, Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass four 1-D arrays to `plt.quiver`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 4)
y = np.arange(0, 4)

# vectors x coordinate values
fx = (0, 1, 1, 2)    
# vectors y coordinate values
fy = (1, 0, 1, 2)


Q = plt.quiver(x, y, fx, fy)
plt.xlim(-1, 4)
plt.ylim(-1, 4)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: I many thanks for your help. My desired final result would be plot the vectors in a "square" presentation instead of diagonally. Basically the arange will give me the origin coordinates for my 2D map.